# spring-4 role mapping ldap

Tags: spring, ldap, authorization

I am new to Spring

Problem Statement:

I have setup ldap server(Apache DS) with roles and users.

I need to authorize the same in my spring application. I need to block the urls, based on the authorization roles coming from LDAP. 
How do I tell my Spring application to authorize the data coming from LDAP.
As of now it is letting me login, but on click on any of the links with the urls given to provide access I am getting access denied(403) exception.

In my knowledge I feel I need to configure the same in spring, but how do I do it, I am not able to figure out.

Comment: are u using method level security with annotation e.g @PreAuthorized ?

Comment: No I am not using @PreAuthorized

Comment: Try adding this and see if it works for you

Comment: I tried adding, did not work. I tries with the annotation @Role as well, but no result.

Comment: could you upload your project in github and post the repo link here.